# error: subquery must return only one column during insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next code:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (id, value1, value2, value3)
      VALUES (
        (SELECT id FROM user_table WHERE some_column = 'data'), 
        (SELECT value1, value2 FROM event_table WHERE type = 'some_type'),
        value3
      )
```

And I am getting next error: `subquery must return only one column`
This error related to second 'select', but I don't understand why. I should return two values and it is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `insert . . .` select`:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (id, value1, value2, value3)
    SELECT ut.id, et.value1, et.value2, <value3>
    FROM user_table ut JOIN
         event_table et
         ON ut.some_column = 'data' AND et.type = 'some_type';
```

Notes:

- It is not clear where `value3` comes from.  I assume it is a constant of some sort.
- This version will not return any rows if the conditions do not match in either table.  I assume this is a feature and not a bug.